# Fast 2-D interpolation in Python with SciPy regular grid to scattered / irregular evaluation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, mesh

I have a regular grid of training values (vectors x and y with respective grids xmesh and ymesh and known values of zmesh)  but an scattered / ragged / irregular group of values to be interpolated (vectors xI and yI, where we are interested in zI[0] = f(xI[0],yI[0]) ... zI[N-1]  = f(xI[N-1],yI[N-1]). This interpolation will be called millions of times as part of an optimization problem, so performance is too important to simply to use a method that makes the grid and takes the trace.

So far, I've been able to find one scipy.interpolate function that comes close to what I want, the Bpf function. However, because it tales a scattered input, I assume that it doesn't have good performance and I'd like to test it against spline, linear,  and nearest neighbor interpolation methods I understand better and I expect will be faster. All of the methods that implement these that I could find that take regular grids as training data (like RectBivariateSpline ) also seem to require regular grids for values to interpolate.

This code will hopefully make clear what I'm asking.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.interpolate as interp

x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,.1)
y = x
xmesh,ymesh = np.meshgrid(x,y)
zmesh = np.sin(xmesh)+np.cos(ymesh)
rbf = interp.Rbf(xmesh, ymesh, zmesh, epsilon=2)
xI = np.arange(0,np.pi,.05)
yI = xI
XI, YI = np.meshgrid(xI,yI)
# Notice how this is happy to take a vector or grid as input   
zI = rbf(xI, yI)
ZI = rbf(XI,YI) # equiv. to zImesh
myspline = interp.RectBivariateSpline(x, y, zmesh)
# myspline takes vectors as input but makes them into meshes for evaluation 
splineoutput = myspline(xI, yI) 
# myspline returns ZI but I want zI
print(splineoutput)
print(ZI)
print(zI)
```

Is there something I can do to use a function like RectBivariateSpline but to get zI (vector) instead of ZI (mesh)? Or alternatively, is there another family of functions that works the way that I want on alternative optimization methods, and if so, what should I look for?

Just a quick reminder that what I'm looking for is a fast optimization technique on with relatively large arrays of data (20,000+ entries), with small distances between grid points, and where the data is pretty smooth. I'm suspect that there is a nice, simple, way to do what I need with existing libraries but I can't find it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.ev.html

I.e. `myspline.ev(xI, yI)`

Comment: That appears to be exactly what I wanted. I knew there was something built in to help. Thanks!

Comment: Also see this answer for the n-dimensional case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983843/fast-interpolation-of-grid-data

Answer (score 4):

From scipy v0.14.0, [`RectBivariateSpline.__call__()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.__call__) takes an optional `grid=` keyword argument which defaults to `True`:

> **grid** : *bool*
>
> Whether to evaluate the results on a grid spanned by the input arrays, or at points specified by the input arrays.

So you could use:

```
splineoutput = myspline(xI, yI, grid=False)
```