# Interpolation over an image for marking of bad pixels in python

Tags: scipy, interpolation, pyfits

Hi I have a fits image that I read in with `pyfits.getdata` which has heavy vignetting along in the corners of the image. I create a second `numpy` array with the same dimensions as the original image, having a value for a bad pixel as 1 and a usable one as 0. To detect point sources I use `pysex` on the original image. The `pysex` routine detects fluctuation in the vignetted area as point sources. How can I interpolate over the array marking the bad pixels. I have tried `scipy.interpolate.griddata`and `scipy.interpolate.interp2d` and the required arguments are not clear, what is the simplest solution?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pysex` or the specifics of how it works, but have you considered trying using a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#examples)?

Answer (score 0):

You have bad pixel at (x0,y0) = 5,10 
and an other one at   (x1,y1) = 50,100

```
output = Scipy.interpolate.map_coordinat(array,np.array([[5,50],[10,100]]))
1bad_value = output[0]
2bad_value = output[1]
```

it's like [x0,x1,x2,x3],[y0,y1,y2,y3] , not very intuitive I admit

You want more, This is a really good post : 
[Fast interpolation of grid data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983843/fast-interpolation-of-grid-data)

But actuallly I would use scipy.filter.uniform_filter for bad pixels. It gives you the value of the average of the neigbourgs. It is not as precise a a cubic interpolation but it is more robust. Even better scipy.filter.median_filter in case you have 2 bad pixels near each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think `map_coordinates` should be able to give you what your want:

```
index_vignetted = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(vignette, point_sources)
```

This will return you a vector with the value of your vignette for the pixel under the location of each point source.