# openCV griddata too slow

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, computer-vision, interpolation

I was following the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364201/image-transformation-in-opencv/10374811#10374811) to correct a distorted image. It works well on small images, however applying it on large images (around 2000x20000) is too slow. griddata takes forever to complete.

I also read other solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724678/1443229), the author uses warpPerspective instead of griddata and remap, but that does not apply to me as I need to correct a distorted image, not simply change view angel

Also there are some discussions about speeding up griddata [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20930910/1443229), but I don't know how to apply that to my case as the code is quite different

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for this forum.  Please read this forum's Help section for what are good questions and how to ask them. Images would also be helpful even if you have to post elsewhere and link to them.